# How to name snapshot containing specific change without it becoming latest snapshot of current version?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

While working on changes in few internal libraries I decided do add suffix to version, so I can use modified library in dependencies without causing trouble to others with my work in progress.
For example:

```
1.1.0-SNAPSHOT --> 1.1.0-mychange-SNAPSHOT
```

However, it caused some problems because snapshot of version `1.1.0-mychange` was still treated as the newest snapshot of version `1.1.0` and it broke some of our builds (and it took someone else some time to notice what was causing problems).

Of course I could simply use `1.2.0-SNAPSHOT` - but what if someone will come up with same idea? (also change was candidate for `1.1.0`, so putting it in higher version didn't make much sense)

**Question**: Is there a better way to have a separate line of snapshots, a way that would protect others from accidentally using my snapshot?

Answer (score 2):

In your case you are working on a branch (or a different code base in general) of the same library, which would then be merged (potentially, at some point, based on some criteria) and as such you should keep the same versioning. Hence, a reasonable approach is to use Maven [classifier](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies).

With classifiers, you would have the following advantages:

- Consumers will not be affected by your changes as you will not impact the official SNAPSHOT dependency
- Consumers will be able to easily switch from one dependency to the other with a manual update of the dependency (adding the `classifier` element) or via the approach presented below.
- You will keep track of the branch/meaning/requirement behind your changes via a meaningful classifier name (recommended)
- Maven will keep the official SNAPSHOT and your classified version in the same Maven repository location (same groupId, same artifactId, same version, that is, GAV) but yet as different dependency (indeed, the truly unique coordinates are GAVC, where the last C stands for Classifier)

So for the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

You could have:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>featureA</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Then consumers could simply decide which dependency to declare or manually change/update it whenever required. Alternatively, they could also apply the following approach to easily double check (compile/test against) the dependency you are working on:

```xml
<properties>
    <dep.classifier></dep.classifier>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test-classifier</id>
        <properties>
            <dep.classifier>featureA</dep.classifier>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <classifier>${dep.classifier}</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What we are doing here:

- We are defining the classifier as a property, the `dep.classifier` property (sample name)
- By default the property is empty, Maven will fetch the official dependency without classifier (nice trick)
- In a profile, we define the classifier we want as a profiled property

Then, the default build will normally use the standard dependency, while running with:

```
mvn clean install -Ptest-classifier
```

or

```
mvn clean install -Ddep.classifier=featureA
```

The build will instead use your dependency (given that it was available on the concerned repository) enabling consumers to easily switch (and test) between development branches/versions/features. I just tested this approach and works fine.